# Appended field Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am having this problem, that whenever i am trying to get value from dynamic section it is not showing anything

the html part:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mcqModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Multiple Choice Question</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
  
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form id="mcq" action="{{ route('poll.mcq') }}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="poll_id" value="{{ $poll->id }}">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Question:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mcqque" name="question[question]">
            </div>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Options</legend>
              <ul class="addli list-group" id="allLi">
                <style>
                  .addinp{
                    float:right;
                    width: 30%;
                    position: relative;
                  }
                </style>
                <button type="button" class="addinp btn btn-success float-right" onclick="newLi(this)"> Add new Field </button>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="correct col-md-2" id="mcqcorrect" >
                  <input type="hidden" name = "inp correct[]" value="0">
                  <input type="text" class="col-md-8" name = "answers[]">
                  
                </li>
              </ul>
              <input type="submit" class="form btn btn-primary" value="Save">
              </form>
            </fieldset>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div
```

> 

script:

```
function newLi(event){
        
        var ul = document.getElementById('allLi');
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.className = 'list-group-item';
        li.innerHTML = ' <input type="checkbox" class="correct col-md-2" id="mcqcorrect" ><input type="hidden" name = "inp correct[]" value="0"><input type="text" class="col-md-8" name = "answers[]">';
        ul.appendChild(li);
      }
```

This newLi is appending the child successfully but

second script:

```
$('.correct').on('click',function(){
          if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.inp').val(1);
          }
          else{
            $('.inp').val(0);
          }
        });
```

on click on the checkbox, I want its input value to be which is working very well for the static HTML part but not for the dynamic part

please help me solve this issue
any help will be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have dynamic added fields on your page you need to change your code a little bit, because when the page is loaded at first the jquery sees only what's initially there... and if there are new elements added jquery doesn't take them in concern... so with this code you check the whole document if there is any element with that class:

```
$(document).on('click', '.correct', function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $('.inp').val(1);
    } else {
      $('.inp').val(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: One more thing can u please tell me how can i get closest text input value of each checkbox?

Comment: You need to wrap the checkbox and text input in the same div and give that div a class and then you can do this: on click `$(this).closest('.wrap-class').find('.inp')`